# JSON to C# Object when posting a data from Angular js controller

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Hi Everyone I need to be able to send an object from angular.js front end for a view model class that has a member property as

```
public class InviteUserBase
{
    public InviteUserBase()
    {

        Tokens = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this object from angular js controller which does not bind to tokens property of above class.

```
 vm.addUser.tokens = [
            { 'registrationVerificationURL': ['https://test/api/v1/#/user-regsitration'] },
            { 'firstName': ['mahesh'] },
            { 'lastName': ['Karki'] },
            { 'customerId': ['15194'] },
            {'customerType': ['Resi'] }
        ];
```

Need help and I cannot use any tools such as JSON.NET or newtonsoft.json

Comment: Whenever you want to know how to format a specific data type you can write a WebApiController with an action that returns an instance of that type and look at the response in your browser.

Comment: Thats a long shot but definitely a sure shot thanks @PeterMorris, will try that one